# How to use mysql column as unix_timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working with mysql and i want to know that how can we use column as unix timestamp where we can store date with time (in single column) like 2019-07-16 15:11:12,How can i do this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking for the [datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type?

Comment: @B001ᛦ: i want to save column name "start_time" and "close_time" in database and want to compare them via api so for this purpose i want to use column as unix_timestamp but i dont know how to use this

Comment: That would be a simple integer. But you cannot do date stuff with such column unless you convert back and forth. Are you sure?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: sorry but not understand your point,please explain

Comment: A Unix timestamp is roughly a number of seconds so the exact column type would be an [integer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) of your choice. But MySQL won't handle it as date. For simple stuff like "give me rows from 2018" or "sort by month" you'll need to convert values, every time, to an actual [date column type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html). For that reason, it might not be the right choice, esp. considering that converting a single Unix time to an actual date in application code is trivial.